# WSO2 API Analytics: From where the data gets into WSO2AM_STATS_DB

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I am fairly new with WSO2 products and currently checking on the ApiM and Analytics products.

I am able to configure the WSO2 APIM and Analytics products successfully with SQL database and now able to get the stats as well.
In further exploring, I want to know from where the data gets inserted into various tables inside WSO2AM_STATS_DB.

If its through events, then can some one please throw light on the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is though a collection of Siddhi Apps running in APIM Analytics which is based on [Stream Processor](https://wso2.com/analytics-and-stream-processing/). You can find corresponding siddhi apps under /wso2/worker/deployment/siddhi-files. Below are the files

```
APIM_ACCESS_SUMMARY.siddhi
APIM_FAULT_SUMMARY.siddhi
APIM_REQUEST_PROCESSOR.siddhi
APIM_WORKFLOW.siddhi
```

These are written using [Siddhi](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi) and here is the link to [siddhi query guide](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/) if you need to understand.

Comment: Thanks Tishan.
Can you please provide me the location once again. I cannot find any such location in home directory.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using APIM version 2.5.0 and Analytics also 2.5.0

Comment: Can you please let me know the directory where can I find these in version 2.5.0

Comment: In that case visit management console of the product(Hosted in <ip>:9443/carbon). In the console there are two sections in right hand side menu namely 'execution plans' and 'scripts'. Those will contain the summarization scripts some written in Siddhi and Spark.